# Xamarin.forms анимация и PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

новичок в Xamarin.
У меня есть представление **Page.xaml** содержащий:

`<Label Text="{Binding GetValue}" />`

В коде **Page.xaml.cs** при инициализации контекст устанавливается следующим образом:

`BindingContext = PageViewModel`

В классе **PageViewModel** есть свойство:

```
    private string _value;

    public string GetValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }

        set
        {
            _value = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("GetValue"));
        }
    }
```

Если меняется свойство, то в представлении все нормально отображается изменение, но я никак не могу реализовать анимацию смены значения, например мне нужно что бы при смене GetValue, текст со старым значением плавно исчезал, потом новый плавно появлялся. Плавное появление я реализовал с помощью PropertyChanged у Label:

```
    async void Label_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var label = sender as Label;

        if (e.PropertyName == "Text")
        {
            label.Opacity = 0;
            await label.FadeTo(1, 2000, Easing.CubicInOut);
        }
    }
```

Значение мгновенно исчезает и новое плавно появляется. ***Так вот собственно вопрос, как реализовать плавное исчезновение Label до того как произойдет смена свойства и начнет работать приведенный выше код появления, не нарушая MVVM Pattern?*** Рассматривал вариант Behaviors и Triggers, но там ничего путного не нашел, такое чувство что во viewmodel до того как менять свойства нужно вызвать метод анимации и дождаться её окончания, но я никак не могу понять как это реализуется не нарушая MVVM. Рассматривал еще MessageCenter, что бы послать сообщение, но в данном случае непонятно как дождаться результат анимации.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties#detect-property-changes - вот тут решение. В статичном поле BindableProperty при создании можно определить метод который и будет делать замену (propertyChanged: OnEventNameChanged), этот метод можно сделать асинхронным и пускать await'ы с анимацией до присвоения, ну или любым другим способ создавать анимацию. Все работает идеально.

Comment: Xamarin таки отличается от WPF потому голосую за открытие этого вопроса, чтобы можно было дать на него ответ.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ откройте вопрос, я дам на него ответ.

Comment: @aepot спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: пример работы]

Данную функциональность можно реализовать с помощью такого класса поведения

```
public class LabelAnimationBehavior : Behavior<Label>
{
    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Label label)
    {
        label.PropertyChanging += Label_PropertyChanging;
        label.PropertyChanged += Label_PropertyChanged;
        base.OnAttachedTo(label);
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Label label)
    {
        label.PropertyChanging -= Label_PropertyChanging;
        label.PropertyChanged -= Label_PropertyChanged;
        base.OnDetachingFrom(label);
    }

    private async void Label_PropertyChanging(object sender, PropertyChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName != "Text")
            return;

        await (sender as Label).Opacity = 0;
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }

    private async void Label_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName != "Text")
            return;

        await (sender as Label).FadeTo(1, 2000);
    }
}
```

Разметка страницы такая

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:App1"
         x:Class="App1.MainPage">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<Grid Padding="5" RowDefinitions="*,*">
    <Label Grid.Row="0"
           FontSize="Header"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           Text="{Binding Value}">
        <Label.Behaviors>
            <vm:LabelAnimationBehavior/>
        </Label.Behaviors>
    </Label>
    <Button Text="Click Me"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>
  </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Класс въюмодели

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private static int _counter = 0;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ClickCommand = new Command(() =>
        {
            ++_counter;
            Value = _counter.ToString();
        });
    }

    private string _Value = _counter.ToString();
    public string Value
    {
        get => _Value;
        set
        { 
            _Value = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Value)));
        }
    }

    public ICommand ClickCommand { get; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант

```
public static class AnimationFadePropertyHelper
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached("Text", typeof(String), typeof(AnimationFadePropertyHelper), null, propertyChanged: OnTextChanged);

    public static string GetText (BindableObject view)
    {
        return (string)view.GetValue(TextProperty);
    }

    public static void SetText(BindableObject view, string value)
    {
        view.SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    async static void OnTextChanged(BindableObject view, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if (view == null)
            return;

        var text = view as Label;

        await text.FadeTo(0, 1500);
        text.Text = (string)newValue;
        await text.FadeTo(1, 1500);
    }
}
```

Применение: `<Label helper:AnimationFadePropertyHelper.Text="{Binding Word}" />`

Comment: Ваш вариант даже получше будет.